# Specifying structure of serialized XML using DataContractSerializer

Tags: xml, database, linq-to-sql

I am creating serialized XML for a LINQ to SQL project using the DataContractSerializer class.  Upon serialization and inspecting the returned object, I get XML that looks like this.

```
- <ContentObject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Data.Model">
  <_x003C_ID_x003E_k__BackingField>1</_x003C_ID_x003E_k__BackingField> 
  <_x003C_ObjectItemState_x003E_k__BackingField>Active</_x003C_ObjectItemState_x003E_k__BackingField> 
  <_x003C_ObjectName_x003E_k__BackingField>6ec555b0ba244ab4a8b2d2f2e7f4185a</_x003C_ObjectName_x003E_k__BackingField>   ETC.
```

I am trying to find out how to simplify the XML structure to just be

```
- <ContentObject xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyProject.Data.Model">
  <ID>1</ID> 
  <ObjectItemState>Active</ObjectItemStat> 
  <ObjectName>6ec555b0ba244ab4a8b2d2f2e7f4185a</ObjectName>    ETC
```

I have tried decorating the wrapper object

```
 namespace MyProject.Data.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ContentObject
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("ObjectName")]
        public string ObjectName { get; set; }      
        [XmlAttribute("ObjectItemState")]
        public string ObjectItemState { get; set; }  ETC
    }
}
```

but this doesn't help.  Can anyone help me find what exactly I need to do to specify the XML structure, either within the class or in the DBML Designer file?  Any link or article would be very helpful too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `DataContractSerializer` as you mentioned, then you have to decorate your structure with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes - not `[Serializable]` and `[XmlAttribute]` and so forth (those are used for regular and XML serializers).

The DataContractSerializer is a strictly "opt-in" serializer - only those fields and/or properties that you specifically mark with `[DataMember]` will end up being serialized; as opposed to the XmlSerializer which is opt-out - it serializes everything unless it's marked with `[XmlIgnore]`.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer : I was mixing technology :  I needed to change the class decorations as follows:

```
[Serializable]
/// <summary>
/// regular Object type, like Client or Poll
/// </summary>
[DataContract(Name = "ContentObject", Namespace = "http://www.myproject.dev")]
public class ContentObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ObjectName")]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "ObjectItemState")]
    public ItemState ObjectItemState { get; set; } ETC.
```

Comment: You beat me to my answer by seconds :-)

Comment: They are no longer act as XmlAttributeAttribute as in your original post. They resemble more XmlElementAttributes.